# Phalcon, how to get the output in both controller and view?

Tags: php, phalcon

If I add the view file "index.phtml", only the view will be displayed

If I want to display the echo in controller, I must delete the "index.phtml" or disable the view in controller

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $this->view->disable();
    echo "this is conntroller";
}
```

How to display both output in controller and view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will show output from echo and then render the view:

```
<?php

class TestController extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        echo 'hello';

        $view = new \Phalcon\Mvc\View();
        $view->setViewsDir(APPLICATION_PATH . '/app/views/');

        $view->start();
        $view->render('test', 'index');
        $view->finish();

        echo $view->getContent();
        die();
    }
}
```

Or put view service in the DI:

```
$di->set('view', function(){
    $view = new \Phalcon\Mvc\View();
    $view->setViewsDir(APPLICATION_PATH . '/app/views/');
    return $view;
}, true);
```

And then use it in controller:

```
<?php

class TestController extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        echo 'hello';

        $this->view->start();
        $this->view->render('test', 'index');
        $this->view->finish();

        echo $this->view->getContent();
        die();
    }
}
```

**P.S.** But I don't recommend this approach. The better way is to assign variables in the view and show them.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $this->view->disable();
    echo "this is conntroller";
    die; // or exit;
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Not works, I don't want to disable the view, I want echo something in controller and load the view

Comment: why do you want to do that? Why don't you use: $this->view->yourvar = 'abc'; and and top of your view, you can show it by "echo $yourvar;"?

Answer (score 0):

I thought controllers are not suppose to display stuff. All action should be put inside controllers and be displayed in views.

Answer (score 0):

[FirePHP](http://www.firephp.org/) will allow you to dump from PHP (controllers, wherever) and see the results in your browsers javascript console log. Only issue is you have to `ob_start()` which will break your redirects during debugging.

Especially handy for AJAX debugging where you aren't showing a fresh rendered page in the browser.

I simply include it in my dependency injection then can use `$this->logger->info()` in the same way I'd use `var_dump()`.

```
    /**
    * FirePHP Logger for dumping into console.
    */
    $di->set('logger', function() {
        //$logger = new \Phalcon\Logger\Adapter\Firephp('debug', null);

        require_once(__DIR__ . '/../../libs/firephp-core/lib/FirePHPCore/FirePHP.class.php');
        ob_start();
        $logger = \FirePHP::getInstance(true);
        $logger->setEnabled(true); // TODO: Config to disable.

        return $logger;
    }, true);
```

If the question is more about how to output from controller and view, in a production environment. The short answer is: You don't, doing so would negate using an MVC framework that organises and separates these different types of things.

Note: Commented out Phalcon adaptor from the incubator, was easier to get the class working directly in my case.